# New changes not taking effect after restarting node server on windows

Tags: node.js

After changing a file inside my node project, I restart the node server but the scripts shown in console are same as the previous version of the code which I have changed. `npm cache clean` is also not working for me. What should I do?

Edit: The files are being cached automatically so changing files does not take effect

Comment: Note that `npm cache clean` clean the _npm_ cache only.

Comment: then what should i do in this case